# Trying to reverse multiple integers in an array - want to know why my code doesn't work

Tags: c, arrays

I **might** have made some very broken/inefficient code here, but so far I've been trying to build it all from scratch.

What I'm trying to do in this code is have the user input 8 integers, and then reverse them.
Meaning if the user inputs `12 21 32 43 54 43 23 54`, the program outputs `45 32 34 45 34 23 12 21`.

This is the code I've made:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
        int input[8];
        char code[20][8];
        char rev[20][8];
        char pos[3];

        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                int j = i+1;
                if(j==1){
                        strncpy(pos, "st", 3);
                }
                else if(j==2){
                        strncpy(pos, "nd", 3);
                }
                else if(j==3){
                        strncpy(pos, "rd", 3);
                }
                else{
                        strncpy(pos, "th", 3);
                }

                printf("Enter the %d%s integer : ",i+1,pos);
                scanf("%d", &input[i]);
                sprintf(code[i],"%d",input[i]);
        }   

        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(code[i]);j++){
                        rev[i][sizeof(code[i]-j)] = code[i][j]; 
                }
        }

        printf("NORMAL OUTPUT \t\t:");
        for(int i = 7; i >= 0;i--){
                for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(rev[i]);j++){
                        printf("%c",rev[i][j]);
                }
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");

        printf("NON-REVERSE OUTPUT \t:");
        for(int i = 7; i >= 0;i--){
                for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(code[i]);j++){
                        printf("%c",code[i][j]);
                }
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");

        printf("INTEGER OUTPUT \t\t:");
        for(int i = 7; i >= 0;i--){
                printf("%d",input[i]);
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");

}
```

It has some fluff, and some debug code in it to help me see where the problem is, but so far it hasn't helped much.

The problem is this. Whenever I try to output the integer array *(as shown by the INTEGER OUTPUT block)*, it displays it perfectly.

Whenever I output the character array 'code' *(as shown by the NON-REVERSE OUTPUT block)*, it displays ALMOST the same thing as the integer array, however, it has minor glitches in it.

The worst output is by the reversed array *(as shown by NORMAL OUTPUT block)*, which is basically a broken string.

Here are three examples of outputs:

Try 1, with single-digit numbers:

```
Enter the 1st integer : 1
Enter the 2nd integer : 2
Enter the 3rd integer : 3
Enter the 4th integer : 4
Enter the 5th integer : 5
Enter the 6th integer : 6
Enter the 7th integer : 7
Enter the 8th integer : 8
NORMAL OUTPUT       :     ÿ²þ   
NON-REVERSE OUTPUT  :8wÙz 7 6 5 4wÙz 3 2 1 
INTEGER OUTPUT      :8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Try 2, with 4-digit integers:

```
Enter the 1st integer : 1234
Enter the 2nd integer : 1234
Enter the 3rd integer : 1234
Enter the 4th integer : 1234
Enter the 5th integer : 1234
Enter the 6th integer : 1234
Enter the 7th integer : 1234
Enter the 8th integer : 1234
NORMAL OUTPUT       :     ¤Aÿ   
NON-REVERSE OUTPUT  :1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 
INTEGER OUTPUT      :1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234
```

Try 3, with 8-digit integers:

```
Enter the 1st integer : 12345678
Enter the 2nd integer : 12345678
Enter the 3rd integer : 12345678
Enter the 4th integer : 12345678
Enter the 5th integer : 12345678
Enter the 6th integer : 12345678
Enter the 7th integer : 12345678
Enter the 8th integer : 12345678
NORMAL OUTPUT       :8 8 8 8 8 8®ßôý 8  
NON-REVERSE OUTPUT  :12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678 
INTEGER OUTPUT      :12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678
```

The more digits in the integers, the less glitchy the non-reversed output is, but the normal output is consistently broken. I have no idea what might be causing this, unless the problem is address-related.

I know that there may be easier way to reverse multiple integers, or strings, but my primary hope here is to find out what exactly is wrong with this code, whether it's the whole structure/strategy that's flawed, or whether I've forgotten to account for something.

Sorry for the length of this post, I just wanted to put all the information out there, just in case it's needed, or someone else needs the help.

**UPDATE1:** Someone suggested I used strlen instead of sizeof, and change 8 to 9 when declaring the array, and it worked... slightly.

Using the same inputs, here are the same tries as before:

Try 1:

```
NORMAL OUTPUT       :      2Øp h1°ü   
NON-REVERSE OUTPUT  :8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
INTEGER OUTPUT      :8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Try 2:

```
NORMAL OUTPUT       :234 4   4 4 4µê12 34Ýæ1
NON-REVERSE OUTPUT  :1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 
INTEGER OUTPUT      :1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234
```

Try 3:

```
NORMAL OUTPUT       :2345678 2345678 2345678ý12345678 2345678 2345678 2345678 2345678 6785ý
NON-REVERSE OUTPUT  :12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678
INTEGER OUTPUT      :12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678
```

The problem with the normal output is still there, the reverse being as broken as always, except for the last one which looks, albeit not reversed, at least has actual numbers in it.

All the updates to the code will be shown here btw: [ReverseInteger.c](https://gist.github.com/MasterTextman/dc5e3f573f46e595400b561d060ee0b4)

Just in case anyone wants an update!

**UPDATE2**: As BLUEPIXY said in the comments, I needed to leave space for the null terminator. `strlen` was counting the null terminator, so essentially when I arrived to the block reversing the integers, it was overwriting the null terminator, breaking the whole string.

In addition to this, I had to initialise the 2D array that I was reversing, which could be done by setting it to {{0}}. My gist is that for every dimension you have to add one more { }.

Fixed code is in the gist link, thanks!

Comment: Use `strlen` for the length of the string. And To write eight digits as a string using `sprintf`, you need `9` areas instead of `8`.

Comment: I'll update the post!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It slightly worked, I think! I updated the post, the problem with the NON-REVERSE OUTPUT is fixed, but the reversed output is still broken.

Comment: I don't know what kind of modification you made. So I have nothing to say.

Comment: I did the same modification you told me: switching all sizeof( with strlen(, and changing code[20][8] and rev[20][8] to code[20][9] and rev[20][9]. Said this in the updated post.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY https://gist.github.com/MasterTextman/dc5e3f573f46e595400b561d060ee0b4 here are all the updates.

Comment: `strlen(code[i]-j)` ?? `strlen(rev[i])` : `rev[i]` must be terminated with a null-character(`'\0'`).

Comment: OH, I see, changed it with `strlen(code[i])-j`, though the problem's still there...

Comment: So `strlen(code[i]-j)` --> `strlen(code[i])-j-1`, `char rev[20][9];` --> `char rev[20][9] = {{0}};`

Comment: That... actually worked pretty well! What does {{0}} do? Also if you posted this as an answer I'd mark it right in a heartbeat.

Comment: `{{0}}` initializes 2D-Array to `0`. (Another method is to set it by copying `'\0'` at end.)

Comment: I see, thank you! I'm gonna add all this to the question since the answer's hidden in the comments.

Comment: Your task sounds: "What I'm trying to do in this code is have the user input 8 integers, and then reverse them. Meaning if the user inputs `12 21 32 43 54 43 23 54`, the program outputs `45 32 34 45 34 23 12 21`".  But your code have: NORMAL OUTPUT, NON-REVERSE OUTPUT, INTEGER OUTPUT... How, declared task and your solution related? :) Where is the code for reversing integers, that is converting `1234` to `4321`, where did come from NORMAL OUTPUT, NON-REVERSE OUTPUT, etc?

Comment: I wrote the code for reversing an array of integers, like `1234, 345` to `543, 4321` (your declared task), then looked at your code and have not understand what you doing there.

Comment: rev is the array that stores the reversed integers, as such the code that effectively reverses them is the loop in which rev is set. NORMAL = Reversed integers, NON-REVERSE = Non-reversed integers, after being converted to char. INTEGER = The original integers. I put these in so that I know whether the error was storing the integers themselves, during conversion, or while I was reversing them and storing them in rev.

Comment: Therefore, NON-REVERSE OUTPUT and  INTEGER OUTPUT are the same? Just non-changed integers from the user's input?

Comment: They are unchanged, and they are SUPPOSED to be the same, meaning that if they are different, some errors are in the code.

Comment: I have understand now, they are the same integers, but printed, in the one case as integers, and in the another case as ascii characters. Right?

Comment: Yes correct, that's how they're supposed to be.

Comment: See my answer update. I added the corrected and simplified version of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your version simplified and corrected:

I was played with your final code from the github and discovered, that it can be simplified. `char rev[20][9]` doesn't needed at all.

Also, I think the `char code[20][9]` should be the `char code[8][20]`. 8 numbers in the string form, which have length to 19 digits (the 20-th item for the `\0` character).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
        int input[8];
        char code[8][20];
        char pos[3];

        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                int j = i+1;
                if(j==1){
                        strncpy(pos, "st", 3); 
                }
                else if(j==2){
                        strncpy(pos, "nd", 3); 
                }
                else if(j==3){
                        strncpy(pos, "rd", 3); 
                }
                else{
                        strncpy(pos, "th", 3); 
                }

                printf("Enter the %d%s integer : ",i+1,pos);
                scanf("%d", &input[i]);
                sprintf(code[i],"%d",input[i]);
        }

        printf("REVERSED OUTPUT \t\t:");

        // Just reads strings from the code[] in the reverse order
        // so, using the additional array rev[] doesn't needed.
        for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--){
                for(int j = strlen(code[i]) - 1; j >= 0; j--){
                        printf("%c", code[i][j]);   
                }
                printf(" ");
        }
        puts("");
}
```

#### My version of solving this task:

**Note:** The printing inputted numbers as ascii characters can be a problem, because `12`, `21`, `23` are non-printing characters in the ascii table, therefore, the unreadable string can happen.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {    
    int size = 8;
    int i, j;
    int arr[size];
    char *ending_arr[4] = {"st", "nd", "rd", "th"};
    char *ending;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(i < 3)
            ending = ending_arr[i];
        else
            ending = ending_arr[3];

        printf("Enter the %d%s integer : ", i + 1, ending);

        scanf("%d", arr + i); 
    }
    puts("");

    printf("Original array:\t");
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }   
    puts("");

    printf("Reversed array:\t");
    for(i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        while(arr[i]) {
            printf("%d", arr[i] % 10);
            arr[i] /= 10; 
        }
        printf(" ");
    }   
    puts("");

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Original array: 12 21 32 43 54 43 23 54 
Reversed array: 45 32 34 45 34 23 12 21
```

Comment: The second method seems to use a mathematical way of reversing the integers, which is pretty cool. Although the *ending part is a bit messy, considering 4 would return 4rd.

Comment: @txtman I have checked it now, the fourth prompt returns `4th`: `Enter the 1st integer : 123
Enter the 2nd integer : 345
Enter the 3rd integer : 456
Enter the 4th integer : 234`.

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot the fact that arrays start at 0.